# Query won't execute because of failed datatype conversion

Tags: sql-server

I have the SQL-server Profiler open and this execution is causing an error.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM fn_ProjectionInventory (@VendorKey
   ,@DeptView
   ,@ProdEK    )', N'@VendorKey nvarchar(6),@DeptView nvarchar(5),@ProdEK nvarchar(2)', @VendorKey=N'100106',@DeptView=N'30003',@ProdEK=N'10'
```

When it executes it outputs this error:

"Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ' 1236  SGPNL' to data type int."

Where is it getting "1236 SGPNL" from? I am familiar SQL syntax, but I am not familiar with executing a query by using a sp_executesql.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Must be an issue with the function

Comment: could you paste your UDF also?

Comment: I don't see anything that suggest you need dynamic here. Why can't you just use a select statement?

Answer (score 0):

I'm betting that the function itself is the problem.

Check the definition of `fn_ProjectionInventory`, you will probably find that is performing the failed implicit conversion.

try running this and see if you get the same error:

```
select * from mydb.dbo.fn_ProjectionInventory(N'100106',N'30003',N'10')
```